# uitableview safe to remove if cell==nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm writing an image editing tool. I have a `UITableview` which is displaying the contents of the documents folder. This is all working as expected. The problem I have is when adding new files or deleting files from the document folder.

When creating or deleting files I call `refreshFiles` before calling reload data, using the check `if(cell == nil)`  results in the creation/deletion of a cell  based on the increased/decreased length of my file array.

The last `UITableViewCell` then takes the filename at the last place of the array as the name for that field. However the new filename could be at any place in the array.
To ensure the correct contents are displayed I have removed the `if(cell==nil)` check, which then redraws all the cells each time this is called.

```
-(void)refreshFiles {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *pathList = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *fileListing = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathList error:nil];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
self.fileList = [fileListing filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
[self.fileview reloadData]

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCel *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  // if (cell == nil) { 
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],self.fileList.count,indexPath.row);
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  //   }

return cell;
}
```

However is this a valid way of working? will the cause me performance issues down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple error in your original code: You set the cell text only if a new cell was allocated, not when a cell is reused. The correct order is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) { 
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [self.fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 2):

So now you are always creating a new `UITableViewCell` instead of reusing a possible queued UITableViewCell.

The check `cell == nil` is there to see if there was already a cell ready to be reused. If not it will be `nil` and you will have to recreate it.

So like I said now you are not using the smart queueing mechanism that Apple has created for the `UITableView`. It is there for performance so if I were you I would still have that check.

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely safe, you can omit the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call and create the cell without reuse identifier.

Of course it means there will be no cell reuse for you, but i found it to be a useful approach if the cells are not heavily using the memory but take lot of UI presentation logic. In such a case I can take the responsibility of cells caching and do it manually which would conflict with the reuseIdentifier logic.

My approach for this situation is to create abstract Section class storing at least the title id, name, section header view and array of Row objects storing at least cell view and related cell info.

As a bonus you have super-easy sections management, e.g. you can implement a smooth sections animation like collapsing and expanding back.

However for the most simple tables I always follow the reuseIdentifier approach as that is much faster to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter's answer implies, I think you may be confused about the purpose if the `cell==nil` logic. You want to keep that in there. If you've deleted items from your `self.fileList`, assuming your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` just returns `[self.fileList count]`, then that's all you need to do and once you do `reloadData`. iOS will take care of getting rid of any old, now deleted, rows. But by taking out the `cell==nil`, you won't let iOS reused the old cells and thus you'll waste memory. Unless you have a good reason to get rid of that `cell==nil` logic, you shouldn't.

Your code snippet has a weird fragment of a statement, though:

```
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],self.fileList.count,indexPath.row);
```

I don't know what that line was supposed to be, so you may want to clarify your code sample.

Bottom line, your solution is inefficient and is probably obscuring some other problem with your code. I wonder, for example, for the purposes of simplifying your post, whether you've removed some salient parts of your `cellAtRowForIndexPath`. Notably, are you creating any `UILabel` controls or anything like that in your real `cellAtRowForIndexPath`? Perhaps you can share the complete methods with us. When I see undesirable results after a `reloadData`, it's often because the user has created some controls in their `cellAtRowForIndexPath`, but failed to account for this fact when reusing a dequeued cell. The typical solution is that if you add subviews to a `UITableViewCell`, that you assign them `tag` properties, and if you're reusing a dequeued cell, that you retrieve those created subviews using `viewWithTag`. See the use of `tag` properties in the discussion of custom cell in the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18).

Maybe this isn't the issue, but regardless, the fact that your code behaves differently when you comment out that `cell == nil` conditional logic means that you have some problem in the details of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Perhaps you can share the complete method with us, as there's nothing obviously wrong with the simplified example (other than that fragmentary line of code).

Comment: @user1662693 More often than not, it's something simple like that! Glad you fixed it!